Positioning of tikz nodes with sub pictures based on the sub picture size
How is it possible to align nodes with sub pictures based on their size?
In the following example the rectangle of the sub picture overlaps the process node p2. Is there a way to positioning the sub picture relative on the sizes of the node p2 and the picture itself without using hard coded offsets?
main.tex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, 
        arrow/.style={->, line width=3pt},
        process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!10, text=black}
    ]
        \node(p1) [process] {1. Step};
        \node(p2) [process, below of=p1] {long long text};
        \node(p3) [process, below of=p2] {3. Step};
        \node(p4) [process, below of=p3] {final Step};
        \draw[arrow] (p1) -- (p2);
        \draw[arrow] (p2) -- (p3);
        \draw[arrow] (p3) -- (p4);
        \node (subpic) [right of=p2] {\includestandalone[mode=tex]{sub}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

sub.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ln/.style={->, line width=3pt},
]
  \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (3cm,1cm);
  \draw (0,0) -- (0.87,0.5) node[right] {$f_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



right of doesn't take the size of the nodes in account. Use right=of from the positioning library. (Or a bigger node distance, of course, but right of is considered deprecated since the positioning library also has on grid.) Q9386, A94396

Like this?

MWE with image which is part of LaTeX installation:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{standalone}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 4mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, line width=3pt},
process/.style= {draw, fill=gray!10, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={process, on chain, join=by arr}]
\node (p1)  {1. Step};
\node (p2)  {long long text};
\node (p3)  {3. Step};
\node (p4)  {final Step};
    \end{scope}
\node (subpic) [inner sep=0pt,
                right=of p2] {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}; %{\includestandalone[mode=tex]{sub}};
\draw   (p2) -- (subpic);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Edit:
Proposed solution differs from OP code in the following:

for node placement is used chains and positioning libraries.
Using positioning library distance between nodes is defined by  right=of p2 instead of right of=p2 in yours MWE). It define distance between nodes borders instead their centers as is the case with your solution. Sine you define it to be 2cm, what is less than width of nodes, consequently nodes p2 and subpic overlap.
library chains provide macro join by which you can define arrows between nodes. I kept their width as you defined, but to my test they are to thick and consequently distracting.


It is not clear what is desired size of image.

In principle, the result looks like what I'm looking for. But I would like to use \includestandalone instead of \includegraphics because than I have to convert all standalone pictures to a pdf before including them. And further, on overleaf \includegraphics does not work with my sub.tex picture. Could you improve your solution the the usage of the mentioned sub.tex picture?

@ThomasK, you can use \includestandalone. Does it make some problem?

Sorry, my mistake. Your example works also with '\includegraphics' and the sub.tex figure. But I did't get it, where is the actually problem with my solution? Inside the scope environment you define the order, the arrow and node style. But is this really the reason for the different result?

@ThomasK, see added explanation to my answer, Is now more clear what is main differences between proposed solution in solution which you use?

Thanks a lot. With your explanation I understand your solution and the differences. :)
